# What are the choices for the Ubuntu desktop GUI and how do I enable them?

Tags: menu, desktop-environments

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed the 12.10 in VM on my laptop. I've installed the Vmware tools as well. However, the VM boots to the command-line. A few questions:

- What are the choices of desktops in 12.10?
- How does one start and stop all the various desktop GUI choices like xdm, kdm, gnome etc?

Within the context of the current terminal session that I have open. I want to try them all before making them one of them permanent via a startup init script.

I've tried xdm but other than Terminal and Nautilus, I can't seem to find a menu that will allow me to view and start all the various applications. Where do I find the equivalent of windows 'start' menu in the xdm desktop (and in other desktops)?

Answer (score 2):

There are many Desktop Alternatives,  Below is a list of most of them.  To install any of them, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands that corresponds with each one you want.

**Gnome Shell**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

**KDE**

```
sudo apt-get install kde-standard
```

**XFCE**

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

**LXDE**

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

**Openbox**

```
sudo apt-get install openbox
```

**Gnome Classic**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```