# Installing multiple Ubuntu distros via wubi?

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi, desktop-environments

I've installed Ubuntu via Wubi, and I want to install other distros/desktop enviroments, like KDE, XFCE, etc. Based on [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide):

> You can install your favorite distro from within Wubi (see the advanced settings) and then once you are in Ubuntu, you can install the other desktop environments as normal packages. Each desktop environment is available as a single package (e.g. kubuntu-desktop). You will not have to reboot to change the desktop, simply log-off and choose the desktop environment in the options at login.

I didn't get meaning of that, so what should I do in order to install multiple distros on Ubuntu?

Comment: See if this [helps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/283488/what-are-the-choices-for-the-ubuntu-desktop-gui-and-how-do-i-enable-them/283500#283500) you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different Ubuntu flavours just install different packages per default. If you installed let's say Xubuntu but also want to have everything installed that would have come with Kubuntu, simply install the kubuntu-desktop package in Xubuntu. You can then select the session to use on the login screen.